# how to resolve Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am getting below  warning as

`WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-1) Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]`

I have already set the method as `POST` but still I'm getting the above error. I'm getting this warning message for my delete controller all other CRUD operations are working fine, except delete.

Please find below code 
Controller mapped deleteproducts :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deleteproducts", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable("productId")int productId) {
        IProductsDAO ip = new ProductsDAOImpl();
        boolean b = ip.deleteProduct(productId);
        if(b)
            return "success";
        else
            return "deleteproducts";
```

here's my jsp view:

```
<body>
<form id="update product form" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteproducts" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="product Id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Id</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="productId" class="form-control" id="productid" placeholder="Enter the product Id you want to delete">
        </div>
    </div>  
</form>
</body>
```

DAOimplementation for delete Method call:

```
public boolean deleteProduct(int productId)
    {
        boolean b = true;
        try
        {
            sess.beginTransaction();
            Products p = (Products)sess.load(Products.class, new Integer(productId));
            sess.delete(p);
            sess.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            sess.getTransaction().rollback();
            b = false;
        }
        return b;
    }
```

can some one now tell me what changes should I make in my code to fix this ?

Thank you!

edit 1:

```
@DeleteMapping(value="/deleteproducts/{productId}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable("productId")int productId) {
        IProductsDAO ip = new ProductsDAOImpl();
        boolean b = ip.deleteProduct(productId);
        if(b)
            return "success";
        else
            return "deleteproducts";
    }
```

still getting a warning as:

```
WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-1) Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand `@RequestMapping(value="/deleteproducts", method= RequestMethod.POST)`
what do you mean by this? You are making a RequestMapping want to delete a record and method is POST?

I would suggest please follow the standard way of development. If you want to delete DeleteMapping, for POST use PostMapping and to retrieve some information you can use GetMapping.

Ideally, it should be

`@DeleteMapping("/deleteproducts/{id}")
public void deleteStudent(@PathVariable long id) {
    deleteproductsRepository.deleteById(id); or some CRUD logic to delete
}`

You can refer to this link for better understanding [REST](http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-crud-rest-service-with-jpa-hibernate)

Comment: can you please show the delete mapping code and error

Comment: ok,i think what you need to do is pass value="/deleteproducts/{id}" like this , how does your method gets @PathVariable("productId") ? you have to pass it through your rest end point itself.

Comment: sorry I dont understand what you're trying to say, can you please elaborate ?

Comment: So I after changing my code I'm getting a new warning as `No mapping for GET /ProjectFE/deleteproducts/` So I think it's not detecting the /{productId} part Do you know what should be done?

Comment: because in your jsp code {productId} (not sure about syntax) action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ProjectFE/deleteproducts/{productId}" should be passed , here you have to pass the id, and update your jsp code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

AS i think request form going to GET Method you can try javascript to submit form with function call.

Please find below code :

```
 <form id="update product form" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/deleteproducts"  method="POST">
  <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="product Id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Id</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="productId" class="form-control" id="productid" placeholder="Enter the product Id you want to delete">
         </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
         <input type="button"  value="submit" onclick="javascript:formSubmit()" name="submit" ></a>
        </div>
       </div>
 </form>



 <script>
    function formSubmit() {
if(!isEmpty(document.from.productId.value)){ //even you can validate values in productId 
    document.form.method='POST';
    document.form.action='/deleteproducts';
    document.form.submit();
}
    )
    <script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After writing the below code

```
@DeleteMapping(value="/deleteproducts/{productId}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable("productId")int productId) {
        IProductsDAO ip = new ProductsDAOImpl();
        boolean b = ip.deleteProduct(productId);
        if(b)
            return "success";
        else
            return "deleteproducts";
    }
```

After this instead of running on a normal browser, try running it on a REST API. I tried it on POSTMAN API and I don't get the error. Look at the below image

[image]